# Auth0 with Authorization Extension not passing roles to Spring Security JWT object

Tags: spring-boot, auth0

I have an Auth0 project that I am using for authentication. I have modeled my Spring code based on [this example](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-security-mvc-sample/blob/master/01-Login).

I am trying to limit an area like this...

```
.antMatchers(ADMIN).hasRole(Role.ADMIN.getRoleName())
```

But when I add my Admin role to my user and try to log back in the JWT does not show any roles when I run...

```
Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>)    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
```

It is empty. How do I pass the roles to my application using Auth0

## More Information

I tried decoding the JWT token and I don't see the role information even being passed....

```
Header
{"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256","kid":"<Removed>"}
Body
{"iss":<Removed>,"sub":<Removed>,"aud":<removed>,"iat":<removed>,"exp":<removed>}
```

So why is Auth0 not passing this information.

Answer (score 1):

Groups, roles and permissions won't be added to the jwt automatically. You have to
create a new rule or modify the default rule which is created after enabling (publishing) the authorization extension.

[Adding roles and permissions to a JWT access token in Auth0](https://medium.com/tojs/adding-groups-roles-and-permissions-to-a-jwt-access-token-in-auth0-827cc7df7662)

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the granted authorities to your principal when you're authenticating it.

I assume you have a custom class that implements `UserDetails` and you overwrite `getAuthorities()`. This method should return an authority called `ROLE_ADMIN`. Notice that the role **should** be prefixed with `ROLE_`

Comment: I am but Auth0 is supposed to handle all of this is my understanding. That comes from Claim rolesClaim = jwt.getClaim("https://access.control/roles"); But it is empty

Comment: Also this doesn't really answer the question with relation to Auth0 at all this just descries how it gets the Authorities IMHO

Comment: then I misunderstood the question. sorry